# Unable to sort a 2D array in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm getting some unique results with this little guy

```
clear
$Datas = @{}
$Datas["Database1"] = "440"
$Datas["Database2"] = "140"
$Datas["Database3"] = "210"
$Datas | sort value
```

The Results are:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                         
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                         
Database3                      210                                                                                                                                                           
Database1                      440                                                                                                                                                           
Database2                      140
```

The results should be:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                         
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                         
Database2                      140
Database3                      210                                                                                                                                                           
Database1                      440
```

Any idea what I am missing? Any reading material to dive into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/09/28/weekend-scripter-sorting-powershell-hash-tables/) solves your problem. In short, try this:

```
$Datas.GetEnumerator() | sort value
```

`value` is not necessary (sort by value by default). Use `name` to sort by name.